# How can I schedule a GitHub workflow to a timezone

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to schedule a GitHub workflow time to work every Wednesday at 10:00 am Amsterdam time UTC+2.

I have no idea how to do this, I've searched many places but there is no official answer by GitHub.

I am looking for a working workaround.
This is my code:

```
name: Daily Hosting Release
    on:
      schedule:
        - cron: '0 10 * * 3'
      workflow_dispatch:
    env:
      CHANNEL: 'cloud'
      CHANGELOG_FILE: 'temp-changelog.txt'
```

Comment: Convert it to utc and then use that?

Comment: @AsadAwadia
 Thanks,
What about winter and summer clocks?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible currently and there is a topic for this on [community - add timezone support to scheduling workflow runs with cron](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13454).

People ae trying to find workaround in this topic but IMHO it will not work with  summer/winter time.